# Redirecting WordPress /.htaccess / HSTS / SSL

Tags: redirect, urls, htaccess

I'm trying to set HSTS up correctly on my website and it is currently "half-working", I need to find the correct way to redirect: `http://www.example.com` to `https://www.example.com` finally to `https://example.com`.

Actually, the website has 1 redirect per URL version:

- `http://www.example.com` 301 redirect to `https://example.com/`
- `http://example.com` 301 redirect to `https://example.com/`
- `https://www.example.com` 301 redirect to `https://example.com/`

I now need to adjust the redirection through my `.htaccess` making it result this way:

- `http://www.example.com`
  301 redirect `https://www.example.com`
  301 redirect `https://example.com`"

I tried a couple of times, but I always end up shutting the website down. Could you please help me to fix this?

Sorry guys, I forgot to mention something important: I have already installed HSTS and it is working on `example.com` but when i test it as `www.example.com` i get "Error: Subdomain , Error: No HSTS header , Error: HTTP does not redirect to HTTPS" 
I'm testing it with hstspreload.org

Comment: basically this is the error i'm getting: Error: HTTP does not redirect to HTTPS
`http://www.example.com` (HTTP) redirects to `https://example.com/`. The first redirect from `http://example.com` should be to a secure page on the same host (`https://www.example.com`).

Comment: Easy to redirect http to https Install Really Simple SSL plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the canonical URL is `https://example.com/...`. (You appear to be describing a pointless intermediary redirect? You should only redirect to the final *canonical* URL, no need for anything in between.)

This is just a standard HTTP to HTTPS redirect.

You can do this using mod_rewrite at the top of your `.htaccess` file. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What the above says is... if the request is for HTTP or www subdomain then 301 redirect to the canonical URL.

However, you should test this with a 302 (temporary) redirect *before* you implement HSTS. If you've already implemented HSTS and visited the HTTPS URL then the *browser* will automatically issue the upgraded request and you will never see the redirect (which is the whole point of HSTS).

---

**UPDATE:**

> Error: HTTP does not redirect to HTTPS `http://www.example.com` (HTTP) redirects to `https://example.com/`. The first redirect from `http://example.com` should be to a secure page on the same host (`https://www.example.com`)"

Ah, it would seem that in order to satisfy the [Submission Requirements](https://hstspreload.org/#submission-requirements) to get on the [HSTS preload list](https://hstspreload.org/) you must first "Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS on the *same host*". (This would, however, seem to be counter-intuitive with regards to SEO and user experience.)

To split the redirect in two and redirect to HTTPS *first*, before the canonical www redirect then do something like the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

// 1. Redirect to HTTP to HTTPS on the same host
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

// 2. Canonical redirect from www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

---

For additional notes about issuing canonical redirects for the HSTS preload list see [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/112264/1243) to the following question on the Pro Webmasters stack:
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/112263/hsts-preload-section-on-htaccess

Comment: Apparently hstspreload is showing me the following error: "Error: HTTP does not redirect to HTTPS `http://www.example.com` (HTTP) redirects to `https://example.com/`. The first redirect from `http://example.com` should be to a secure page on the same host (`https://www.example.com`)" just when i check it with www with it sorry I should have specified that before! .-.

Comment: Ah, I see. I've updated my answer with an alternative two-stage redirect.

Comment: I think that's what i was looking for, thank you very much. Also i've been advised about the performance but I'm more focused on security right now, even if some say that redirection could also cause security issues even if it looks the only way to fix this bloody HSTS(which is very recommend apparently) but   I can't try it right now since i got a little issue with my pc, i might open an other post to get more help from the community .-.  For now, thanks again.